# Configuring quartz job scheduler in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, scheduler, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to configure quartz job scheduler in Elastic Beanstalk , In my local machine it works well , But in Amazon's Beanstalk it doesn't! 
I tried both 'Worker environment' and 'Web server environment' in Beanstalk same result.

```
SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory();
    Scheduler sched = schedFact.getScheduler();

        JobDetail job = newJob(Run.class)
          .build();
        Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
                .withSchedule(dailyAtHourAndMinute(21,54).inTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30")))
                .build();

      sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
      sched.start();


public class Run implements Job{

public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("hello");
    //sending post message to another server.
}
```

Why Beanstalk treats the code differently? ,and how to make it work?